# Crashlytics WriteZStream stacktrace

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mono, crashlytics

I have a "hard to read" crashlytics log in a live Xamarin iOS app. This issue affects almost 80% of the users and I am struggling to decipher it.

Please have a look at the log in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/sanandrea/7e381449b66a85a510bf192c32554a0b)

I have uploaded the dSYM file in the Crashlytics dashboard but the log remains the same. Is it normal for a Xamarin App this type of log?

I do not even know what source file of the app causes the crash.

I have the following code in AppDelegate.cs:

```
override public bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions){
//...
    Setup.EnableCrashReporting (() => {
                    var crashlytics = Crashlytics.SharedInstance;
                    crashlytics.DebugMode = true;
                    Crashlytics.StartWithAPIKey ("my_key");

                    Fabric.With (new NSObject[]{ crashlytics });

                    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += AppDomain_CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
                    TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException;
                }, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension (typeof(AppDelegate).Module.Name));
}
```

and the following methods:

```
    void TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException (object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        var ex = e.Exception;
        Setup.CaptureManagedInfo(ex);
        Setup.CaptureStackFrames(ex);
        Setup.ThrowExceptionAsNative(ex);
    } 

    void AppDomain_CurrentDomain_UnhandledException (object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Setup.CaptureManagedInfo(e.ExceptionObject);
        Setup.CaptureStackFrames(e.ExceptionObject);
        Setup.ThrowExceptionAsNative(e.ExceptionObject);
    }
```

Am I missing something on Fabric configuration here?